It is showing There is an attribute or id missing
Website is not opening beause of error in line 96](https://i.sstatic.net/JljzMa2C.jpg)
The error says  'a form field element has neither an id nor a name attribute this might prevent the browser from collecting out of filling the form'.
Th Applicationno. is of 15 digits please give the correct code for this error

Please post the relevant part(s) of your code. Your current description is not sufficient for anyone to help you.
